# Find bluetooth device in web application using Java

Tags: java, bluetooth, bluecove, jsr

Is this possible to detect bluetooth device in web application using java bluetooth library? 
As currently I have one button "Detect Device" in jsp page, which use server device's bluetooth and find nearest bluetooth enable devices by using jsr-82 (Bluecove). The issue is its detect bluetooth enable devices nearest to server (as it use server's bluetooth) not from the client device's bluetooth.In my case assume server is **laptop** as i had run my web app on it now i'm hitting request from another **laptop1** than rather than using  **laptop1**'s bluetooth it still use server's (**laptop**) bluetooth to detect bluetooth enable devices.
I'm using Bluecore Library in app.
Any suggestion please

Comment: What is the wanted behaviour? To detect devices via client' s bt stack? If so, you' ll have to find a way to execute the detection on client side. Like via js or the like. If it is possible in the first place.

Comment: Yes Flidor, expected behaviour is to detect devices via client's bt stack. So in nutshell the java bluetooth library (jsr-82) doesn't provide this feature.I must think how to to do with js. had you any idea to implement this feature via js?any clue please? Thanks.